# Shift + mouseover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, methods

I'm trying to detect whether the shift key is being pressed while the cursor is moved over a particular element. The function fires, but only *after* I click on another element first. Is there some way to work around this? I've tried setting focus to both the document and element, and tried creating a pseudo-click function but so far nothing has worked.

For example, the following code works only after I click another element on the page:

```
$("#selector").mouseover(function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey) {
        console.log("the shift key is pressed");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: how could the action fire up, if it's set on hover? there is some different problem with the code (beside the posted part), i suspect.

Comment: @dusoft: I've tested in a completely new document with no other javascript/jQuery (aside from the jQuery source) and a single element on the page with the same results. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Helpful: How do I check if the mouse is over an element in jQuery?https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273566/1066234

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check this on the keypress event:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {

  if(e.shiftKey) {
    pressed = true; // pressed is a global varialbe. Be carefull of the scope
  }

}
```

then on the keyup:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
   pressed = false;
});
```

then do:

```
$("#selector").mouseover(function(e){
    if(pressed) {
        console.log("the shift key is pressed");
    }
});
```

---

or the other way around :

```
$("#selector").mouseover(function(e){
    isover = true;
});
```

and

```
   $(document).keypress(function (e) {

      if(e.shiftKey) {
        alert("do something")
      }

   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood 100% of what you're trying to do, but I think one of the two should work.

Comment: @marcgg: Thanks for the response. It turned out that I needed to adjust what I was doing a little, but this answered my initial question.

Comment: Too complex. KISS (Keep it short and simple). Check out Martin Schaer's Answer! :-)

Answer (score 8):

It is not necessary to store in a variable when the shift key is pressed and released. You can achieve what you are trying to to like this:

```
$('#selector').mouseover(
    function(e){
        if (e.shiftKey)
        {
            console.log("the shift key is pressed");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This should be the right answer :-) please replace .click() with .mouseover()

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code like this and it works perfectly.  You do have to "shift" then mouseover, though.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    loadHandler = function(){
        $("#selector").mouseover(function(e){
            if(e.shiftKey) {
                alert("the shift key is pressed");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadHandler();">
<div style="border:1px solid black" id="selector">

    <br/>
    <br/>

    This is a div.

    <br/>
    <br/>

<div>
</body>
</html>
```

What type of element is it being applied to?

Comment: @Mark: It was being applied to an img, however I needed to adjust what I was doing. Thanks for your response though - it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Working sample,

MouseEvent.shiftKey, MouseEvent.ctrlKey

[MouseEvent.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey)

[MouseEvent.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey)

```
   <img onmouseover="keypress_test(event)" onmouseout="keypress_test(event)">


    function keypress_test(event) {

             // false, no press, 
             // true, pressed

              console.log(event.ctrlKey)

              console.log(event.shiftKey)
       }
```