# Jquery: How to add a delay to mouseleave so if someone accidentally hovers off the element unintentionally, it still stays open

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseleave, mouseenter

THE hoverintent plugin is the opposite of what I need.
I have a .popup that is triggered by .trigger, when i hover off of it, i want .popup to NOT fadeout for a few seconds, but if I hover off, then hover on again, cancel the fadeout that was going to happen and keep the .popup open.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

This DOESN'T work, but it was an idea:

```
 $('.trigger').hover(function(){
        $('.popup').fadeIn(600)
    }, function() {
        $('.popup').delay(2000, function(){
            if ($(this).blur() = true) {
                $('.popup').fadeOut(600)
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the jQuery [HoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) is exactly what your looking for.

The timeout property will set the amount of time the mouse needs to be OUT of the area before the out function is called.

Quote from the hover intent website:

> timeout:
>   A simple delay, in milliseconds, before the "out" function is called. If the user mouses back over the element before the timeout has expired the "out" function will not be called (nor will the "over" function be called). This is primarily to protect against sloppy/human mousing trajectories that temporarily (and unintentionally) take the user off of the target element... giving them time to return. Default timeout: 0

To set it up...

```
$('.trigger').hoverIntent({
     over: startHover,
     out: endHover,
     timeout: 2000
});
```

Then define the functions to handle `over` and `out`

```
 function startHover(e){
    //your logic here
    $('.popup').fadeIn(600)
 }

 function endHover(){
     //your logic here
     $('.popup').fadeOut(600)
 }
```

EDIT:

You can also adjust the `interval` property to increase/decrease the amount of time for the startHover function to fire...the default is set to 100 milliseconds...you can set it to zero to fire off the popup as soon as the mouse enters the trigger area if youd like.

Comment: There are settings to fine tune everything. The 'timeout' property sets the delay before the 'out' function is called

Comment: So the `startHover` function would show your popup and the `endhover` function would remove it. The timeout would set a delay before the end function is called when you mouseout of the area...achieving the effect that your desire

Comment: Edited about to include your fadeIn/fadeOut logic

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest way to do it, without additional plugins:

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    $('.popup').fadeIn(600);
}, function() {
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        if ($(this).blur() = true) { // off topic: you should to check this condition ;)
            $('.popup').fadeOut(600);
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

setTimeout() and clearTimeout() are native JS functions of HTML DOM Window object since forever.

Comment: for anybody, who stumbles upon this like i did: there's a [very similar solution to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery/1670561#1670561), that i liked better. for example, the `if ($(this).blur() = true)` condition is entirely wrong imo.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the jquery hoverintent plugin.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
$(".triger").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find("popup").fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("popup").delay(200).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This one DOES NOT WORK, because when You get back with the mouse over the .triger within the delay time, it will still fadeOut anyways... just with the 200 delay.