# jQuery check hover status before start trigger

Tags: jquery, triggers, slider

i create a small slider plugin with jquery. the images would slide 5% in from left or right when the mouse is over the left or right controll div. On click the image slides in to 100%

the problem is that when move the mouse during the full slide in animation from the left to right control div i coudnt check if the mouse is always over the left div to trigger the mouseover event again. the result is that the image from the left and the from the right is show 5%.

Is there a way to check the mouseover like this one?

```
if($(this).mouseover())
$(".right").trigger("mouseover");
```

the code of a controller div look like this

```
        $(".right",this).bind({
            mouseover:function(){
                if( vars.current == $("img").length-1 || vars.running) return false;
                $("img:eq("+(vars.current+1)+")").removeAttr("style").css({position:"absolute",left:"100%","z-index":vars.current+1}).show().animate({left:"95%"}, {queue: false})
            },
            mouseleave:function(){
                if( vars.current == $("img").length-1 || vars.running) return false;
                $("img:eq("+(vars.current+1)+")").animate({left:"100%"}, {queue: false , complete:function(){ $(this).hide() } });
            },
            click:function(){
                if( vars.current == $("img").length-1 || vars.running) return false;
                vars.running = true;
                $("img:eq("+(vars.current+1)+")").animate({left:"0%"}, {queue: false, complete:function(){ 
                    $("img:eq("+vars.current+")").hide(); 
                    $(this).css({"z-index":0})
                    vars.current++;
                    vars.running = false;
                    if($(this).mouseover())
                    $(".right").trigger("mouseover");
                } } );
            }
        })
```

i use the way from the other answer... but its deletet....

```
mouseover:function(){
                isOver = 'right';
                if( vars.current == $("img").length-1 || vars.running) return false;
                $("img:eq("+(vars.current+1)+")").removeAttr("style").css({position:"absolute",left:"100%","z-index":vars.current+1}).show().animate({left:"95%"}, {queue: false})
            },
            mouseleave:function(){
                isOver = false
                if( vars.current == $("img").length-1 || vars.running) return false;
                $("img:eq("+(vars.current+1)+")").animate({left:"100%"}, {queue: false , complete:function(){ $(this).hide() } });
            },
            click:function(){
                if( vars.current == $("img").length-1 || vars.running) return false;
                vars.running = true;
                $("img:eq("+(vars.current+1)+")").animate({left:"0%"}, {queue: false, complete:function(){ 
                    $("img:eq("+vars.current+")").hide(); 
                    $(this).css({"z-index":0})
                    vars.current++;
                    vars.running = false;
                    if(isOver)
                    $("."+isOver).trigger("mouseover");
                } } );
            }
```

by using the var isOver i could trigger the left or right

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To check whether something is being hovered, you can use the :hover selector, e.g.:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    if ($('#hello').is(':hover')) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AyAZx/5/

Comment: I really like the brevity of this solution. Perhaps this is why there is no additional jQuery function to check whether the mouse is over an element.

Comment: that pseudo is unsupported, so I'm unsure whether this is a solution or not.

Comment: this solution does not work with jQuery 1.9 and higehr, cf @lorddarq

Comment: dunno. I tested with 1.8 back then in october and it still didn't work. So its quite possible. But i don't think it has anything to do with the jquery part. Rather more with the css support, but I may be wrong.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, I believe the :hover pseudo only works with the .find() method. Testing the .find() with pseudo :hover for length should get the result you want.

Comment: **Warning**: `:hover` is not a valid jQuery selector:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ (source: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11574)

Comment: It still works if the browser supports `document.querySelectorAll(':hover')`

Answer (score 22):

actionshrimp's answer is broken as of jQuery 1.9.1.

Use instead

```
$("#idOfYourElement:hover").length > 0
```

in your if condition

http://jsfiddle.net/mathheadinclouds/ZKGqe/

Comment: Excellent work keeping the thread up to date. StackOverFlow should actually have a deprecated flag...