# jQuery, Mouseleave not fired on container when moving cursor fast

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a bit of a bug.
Well, the code on jsfiddle speaks for itself, to provoke the bug move your mouse quickly over the red box (to one side or the other).

A quick explanation:
I have a list of items, when i hover them i show an overlay div on their positions, i bind an mouseenter on the list item, and an mouseleave on the overlay div, but if you move the cursor to fast, the mouseleave is never triggerd.

Any ideas? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/QH3LV/22/

Comment: I cannot reproduce this bug, but you might try setting a timeout to hide the overlay div, and clear the timeout on both mouseover on the list item, and mouseleave on the overlay. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery/1670561#1670561

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/QH3LV/29/) is what you are looking for.

There should be no problem in placing the hidden `div` inside the `li` tag

Comment: The bug still occurs when your inside the document.body, any other suggestions?

Comment: Edited: try the new demo. Is this ok?

Comment: @AlexBay would you be kind enough to explain why this is happening? I'm experiencing a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216637/any-idea-why-mouseleave-event-is-not-registering-when-moving-the-cursor-fast - the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/abitdodgy/7rFb6/1/

Comment: @dee I added a reply to your question, check it out.