# Jquery condition check is(':hover') not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hover

```
$('.xx').mouseenter(function(){
  if($(this).is(':hover'))
    alert('d');
  else
     alert('f');
});
```

Here is my code, it should alert 'd' but every time it alerts 'f'
What's error Here

Answer (score 33):

```
function idIsHovered(id){
    return $("#" + id + ":hover").length > 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mathheadinclouds/V342R/

Comment: This works perfectly. I'm not sure why this isn't upvoted. It accomplishes exactly what the OP needs, without having to set flags all over your code.

Answer (score 17):

[:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3ahover) is a CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Pseudo-classes), not a jQuery selector. It cannot be reliably used with [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) on all browsers.

Comment: so how will i check is mouse over an element or not

Comment: The link in Connell's answer is quite helpful.

Comment: @Rocket, and you would be right, on Firefox and Chrome at least. However, Internet Explorer 8 does not seem to support that.

Answer (score 5):

As Frederic said, [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:hover) is part of CSS and is not a selector in jQuery.

For an alternative solution, read [How do I check if the mouse is over an element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery/1273609#1273609)

> Set a timeout on the mouseout to fadeout and store the return value to
>   data in the object. Then onmouseover, cancel the timeout if there is a
>   value in the data.
>
> Remove the data on callback of the fadeout.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this-

```
$('.xx').hover(function(){        
        alert('d');
    }, function() {
       alert('f);
    });
```

Comment: how it's help me to check parent's hover out !

Answer (score 2):

```
x.filter(':hover').length
```

This may be also usable when you already had queried some objects / or inside callback function.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just use .hover?

```
$(".xx").hover(function(){
    alert("d");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
flag = ($('.xx:hover').length>0);
```

So you can find out if the mouse is, the object

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little **jQuery plugin** that checks if the mouse is over an element.

**Usage:**

`$("#YourElement").isMouseOverMe();`

**Example:**

```js
(function($) {

  var mx = 0;
  var my = 0;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) { // no expensive logic here
    mx = e.clientX; 
    my = e.clientY;
  })

  $.fn.isMouseOverMe = function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    var el_xmin = $el.offset().left;
    var el_ymin = $el.offset().top;
    var el_xmax = el_xmin + $el.width();
    var el_ymax = el_ymin + $el.height();
    return mx >= el_xmin && mx <= el_xmax && my >= el_ymin && my <= el_ymax;
  };

}(jQuery));

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  console.log($("#div").isMouseOverMe())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click inside or outside of the yellow box</h2>
<div id="div" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:yellow;margin-top:50px"></div>
```