# if condition checking two selectors for hover, if hover, text line underline

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Simplified update, *nevermind* using a variable.** *(original question was using one selector as a variable and doing this)*

Essentially why will below not work.

*Note::*  When not declaring `||` aka second selector this *worked* fine. But **then** what it does is doesn't allow the once css natural `:hover` method on the text, so that is why I'm trying to add the second selector here in the first place. **I need to hover an image, and the see the corresponding text link `hover`, and I also need to maintain hovering over corresponding text link alone to have the `hover` underline effect.** Any suggestions as how to get here if this cannot done with CSS / sass nor using `:hover` in jQuery as a stable option?

```
setInterval(function(){
    if $("#t1").is(":hover") || $(".thumba").is(":hover")) {
       $(".thumba").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    }
    else {
       $(".thumba").css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
}, 200);

setInterval(function(){
    if $("#t2").is(":hover")) || $(".thumbb").is(":hover")) {
       $(".thumbb").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    }
    else {
       $(".thumbb").css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
}, 200);
```

---

**Another example:**

You have an image, say image a.)

`<img src="`**[        image a         ]**`">`

*then you have a paragraph with some text:*

`<div`>blahblahloremipsum `<a href="#">`**clickhere**`</a>` blachhhhhhh`</div>`

I want to hover over image a and allow click here to have an underline, I would like to 'hover out' and the underline to go away. I would also like this not only on the image but as standard with the text link, basically if you hover over click here and not the image it *still* will underline.

**Another attempt:** (but here the underline doesn't unattach after mouse is no longer hover)

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {    
    if($('#t1').is(':hover') || $('.thumba').is(':hover')) {
        $('.thumba').css({'text-decoration':'underline'});
    }
    else {
        $('.thumba').css({'text-decoration':'none'});
    }
});

$(document).mousemove(function() {    
    if($('#t2').is(':hover') || $('.thumbb').is(':hover')) {
        $('.thumbb').css({'text-decoration':'underline'});
    }
    else {
        $('.thumbb').css({'text-decoration':'none'});
    }
});
```

*take a look: here (link below) it describes using it if ONE instance, this is why it's likely failing for me and is not the solution; but I don't see a solution on this thread for multiple.* "(This only works when the selector matches only 1 element though - See Edit 3 for more)"

[Detect IF hovering over element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery)

Comment: What? What do you mean is hover?

Comment: check your parenthesis

Comment: `:hover` is not a valid jQuery selector https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the underline on hover effect on the text link just using CSS:

```
.thumbb:hover,.thumbb-hover {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Then you detect the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on the images:

```
$('#t1,#t2')
.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.thumbb').addClass('thumbb-hover');
})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.thumbb').removeClass('thumbb-hover');
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1f86wLn8/1/). And here's a [fiddle with two images](https://jsfiddle.net/1f86wLn8/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another parenthesis at the end, as well as remove one after the first condition:

```
if($thumbone.is(":hover") || $('.thumba').is(":hover")) {
```

And you might want to refer to this question for checking for hover:

[Jquery condition check is(':hover') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010267/jquery-condition-check-ishover-not-working)

Comment: I don't understand why the above has been marked-up - has been tested several times over and failed based on my question.

Answer (score -1):

A.O. is right, check the parenthesis. Also, everytime I use jquery on html classes, I make sure I grab the first one. It is the default functionality, but it's always nice to explicitly declare it.

```
if($thumbone.is(":hover") || $('.thumba').first().is(":hover")) {
```

Comment: You just pasted his answer?

Comment: You did not, you added it hours after the other guy.

Comment: I added the ".first()"