# AJAX Kendo Tooltip Race Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, kendo-ui

I am making an AJAX call to retrieve some data via a POST request. Then, I am using that data to create a tooltip. Here's the code:

```
j$("#selectorID").one('mouseover',
    function(e) {
        var ticketType = e.target.classList[2];
        var ticketID = j$(e.target).data("ticket-id");
        j$.post("/Some/Url/",
            { "ticketID":ticketID, "ticketType":ticketType },
            function(r) {
                var title = r["title"];
                var tooltip = j$(e.target).kendoTooltip( { content: title, position: "top" } ).data("kendoTooltip");
                if (j$(e.target).is(":hover")) { tooltip.show(); }    // Race condition
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I believe there is a race condition because the tooltip, even after my mouse moved off of it, will still appear. Then I have to put my point on the element, and then move it off again, to make it disappear. What can be done to solve this?

I tried a few different things, including the `if (j$(e.target).is(":hover"))` condition you see there. But it still doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I think you need to target a DOM element in the show(), like tooltip.show($("#target")); http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/tooltip#methods-show

Comment: I tried that as well. There is no effect. The issue is not that it is NOT showing. The issue is that it is showing when it should not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I actually found out the answer to my own question finally after a few hours of searching.

**The issue that I was seeing on my UI -- that the tooltips wouldn't go away and there were sometimes 2 tooltips displaying at the same time -- was not the result of a race condition.**

It was instead a result that when you use multiple kendo tooltip instances in the same web page, you need to manually hide/show them to ensure there will not be a stray tooltip.

The problem, a an overview of the soltuion is described [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/tooltip-doesn't-always-remove-itself).

Specifically, I solved my problem by adding:

```
j$("#selectorID").hover(function() {}, 
        // Handler for when the pointer is leaving an element
        function(e) {
            if (j$(e.target).data("kendoTooltip") !== undefined) {
                j$(e.target).data("kendoTooltip").hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Jquery condition check is(':hover') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010267/jquery-condition-check-ishover-not-working).

:hover is a CSS pseudo class and not a jQuery selector that can be used with .is().

Try this instead:

```
var id = $(e.target).prop("id");                      
if ($("#" + id + ":hover").length > 0) { tooltip.show(); }
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OVihi)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I tried what you mentioned, and unfortunatley I am getting `unsupported pseudo: hover`. Is there another way around this? Is your thinking that my condition in the `if` is not evaluating correctly, which is what is causing the tooltip to show when is should not?

Comment: The tooltip doesn't always show up incorrectly, only randomly. So I am not sure if it is the condition.

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo, what about checking mouseout like this: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OVihi