# CoffeeScript If Statement not Working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've looked at the CoffeeScript documentation, but can't get this to work.

```
if $("#main").hover
    alert('clicked')
```

When I reload the page, the alert always pops up. I have it properly indented in my `.js.coffee` file, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: What are you even trying to *do* with the `if` statement? That's not how you'd do something when you hover on an element.

Comment: I was trying to detect whether or not the element was `hovered`.

Comment: Then you should attach an event handler like normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $(#"main").hover will always return true, that is why the alert is always triggered.

.hover is just returning the "hover" function from jQuery which will evaluate to true in an if statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when hover events fire over #main (which could fire a LOT, btw), you might try:

```
$('#main').hover () -> 
  do_something()
```

If you just want to determine in a given moment whether or not the mouse is currently hovering #main, you should do:

```
if $('#main').is(':hover') 
  do_something()
```

See also [Detect IF hovering over element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery)