# Mouseout stop the function

Tags: jquery

i'm here again :D

I tried to use .stop() for stop my function when mouseout, but doesn't work.

```
        function loop(){
        $('.slider').stop().animate({"left": "-=50"},600,loop);
    };

    $('.botao-dir').mouseover(function(){
        .loop();
    });
```

What i want to do is when my mouse is over the (.botao-dir) the divs add "-50 left" for the style, and, when my mouse is out, the animation just stop.

And there's a way to put an max to add left?

Example: When my divs get the "-500 left", the animation just stop.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery).

Basically check to see if the mouse is still hovering over the element before looping.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/4hzyG/2/)

```
if ((parseInt($('.slider').css("left"), 10) > -500 ||
    $('.slider').css("left") == "auto") &&
    ($('.botao-dir').is(":hover"))) {
    $('.slider').animate({
        "left": "-=50"
    }, 600, loop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way stop at `-500px` is to add a check in your loop.

```
function loop() {
    if (parseInt($('.slider').css("left"), 10) > -500 ||
        $('.slider').css("left") == "auto") {
        $('.slider').animate({
            "left": "-=50"
        }, 600, loop);
    }
    console.log($('.slider').css("left"));
};

$('.botao-dir').mouseover(function () {
    loop();
});
```

Simple Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4hzyG/1/

Comment: Your example in jsfiddle doesn't work. I can do the limit to add left, but the event mouseout i don't.

Comment: The CSS isn't setup correctly but the code does work. Check the console for verification. I recommend integrating the logic to verify it yourself.

Comment: @user2154508 I updated the working example so the CSS works with the code. Give it another look: http://jsfiddle.net/4hzyG/1/