# Jquery - is(':hover') not working in IE nor Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this submenu that opens with mouseover, and all was good until I tested on firefox. Seems like this code doesnt work on IE nor firefox, is() isnt working. Any ideas?

this is my code:

```
$("#m4").mouseenter(function () {
  m4 = false;
  submenu(2)
});
$("#m4").mouseleave(function () {
  if ($("#panel2").is(':hover')) {
    m4 = false
  } else {
    m4 = true
  }
  submenu(2)
})
$("#panel2").mouseleave(function () {
  m4 = true;
  submenu(2)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9PGh6/1/

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery) might be relevant

Comment: Should work the same on FF as on IE

Comment: I believe the problem is that the browser registers a mouseleave of `#m4` *before* you mouseenter `#panel2`, since they are not nested elements. You need to either nest them somehow, or introduce a `setTimeout` before your callback code is run.

Comment: used a setTimeout, it worked fine. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
if ($("#panel2").is(':hover')) {
```

by

```
if ($("#panel2:hover").length > 0){
```