# anyone know how to write PHP in CSS

Tags: php, css

IF

```
.fpss-template-uncut .navigation li.active,
.fpss-template-uncut .navigation li:hover
```

Then

```
.fpss-template-uncut .navigation-title {color: orange;}
```

How to write this code in CSS?

Comment: php parser/translator only process the files with .php extension. you can use js TO customize CSS

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/), CSS pre-processors.

Comment: I'm absolutely lost, why do you need an 'if' clause? Simply write it as is, you're already using a selector and a child class, or am I missing something?

Comment: show us the html code please

Answer (score 0):

Super crude way if I understand somewhat what you want to do:

```
if (false !== stripos('your_container', '.fpss-template-uncut .navigation li.active, .fpss-template-uncut .navigation li:hover'))
{
    echo '.fpss-template-uncut .navigation-title {color: orange;}';
}
```

But you really don't specify so I could be way off.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you will write...

```
$file = 'style.css';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new style to the file
$current .= "Your new css style here.";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

But according to your question, you only wanted to make that navigation title to orange, why not setup jquery on it?

check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8981521/2922445

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way Ive ever found to use php within css, its easy to set up and lets you be a lot more flexable

[php in css the easier way](http://westcoastmarketing.ca/sass-is-fat-use-php-code-in-css-files/)

Comment: Hello, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and in particular the section regarding links.