# how to call a function based on mouse hover property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

```js
function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    var isHovered = $('#theEnd').is(":hover");
    if (isHovered == "True") {
        return youWon();
    }
    else {
        alert("You lost! try again!")
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, the code always defaults to the else statement even when I'm hovering over the div element with the id="theEnd"

Comment: "True" should read ===true

Comment: Why in the world are you using a string boolean representation? `"True" == true` yields `false`

Comment: @MartinWebb Thanks

Comment: No problem that kind of stuff you learn as go. Don't stop asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect IF hovering over element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isHovered` is already a boolean, you don't need to check if it is true or false just do this:

```
if (isHovered) {
    // ...
```