# detect when mouse moves outside of an element

Tags: javascript

`mousemove` is fired when mouse is moving over an element. How can I detect when the mouse is moving outside of an element? In other words, anywhere on the page besides the div in the snippet. Not when the mouse leaves but fires whenever the mouse is moving outside of the element.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    document.body.classList.add('mouse-moving');
 });
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.mouse-moving {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `mouseleave` ?!

Comment: I think I have explained this badly. I want to detect when the mouse is moving outside of the div. Not when it leaves the div.

Comment: anywhere on the page besides the div?

Comment: if it's outside the div, then the div won't get any events about it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Yes, @oMiKeY, that is what I want to do.

Comment: You can always just put `mousemove` on the entire `body` tag. But please, be sure to use `throttle` or `debounce` if you do.

Comment: Also, you could inspect weather a tag is under the mouse by querying on it's `:hover` pseudoclass. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981463/detect-if-hovering-over-element-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks @Gherman, I used the latter and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.onmouseover = ()=> document.body.classList.add('mouse-moving');

 div.onmouseout = ()=> document.body.classList.remove('mouse-moving');
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.mouse-moving {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```