# Select an element is visible from duplicated html elements and check if is is being hoverover - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to verify if a html element is not being hoverover (i mean when mouse leaves that div) in order to hide another element. The problem is that the element i need to check the status is generated dynamically for another third party library and it can be duplicated. The html looks like this: Just one of them is visible at a time

```
<div class="jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup" style="visibility: hidden;">
  .... 
</div>

<div class="jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup" style="visibility: visible;">
  .... 
</div>
```

So i was trying to do something like this:

```
if (!$('.jqx-menu-popup').is(':hover')) 
{                
    $('#' + 'jqxmenu' + elementHover).jqxMenu('close');
}
```

but because there are multiple instances of the div the is(':hover') trigger an exception .

So i thought about something like this to try to get the div which is visible then verify if it is being hoverover:

```
var a = $('.jqx-menu-popup:visible')

if (!a.is(':hover')) {                  
    $('#' + 'jqxmenu' + elementHover).jqxMenu('close');
}
```

but base on jquery documentation "Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout"

Any ideas how can i achieve what i want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8981521/2479903

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looping over each of the elements with [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) (regardless of whether they start off hidden or not), and attaching a `mouseout` event handler (which can be done through jQuery's [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method). This would search the [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) (or similar) and set the `visibility` to `visibile`, while optionally setting the current element to hidden.

```js
$('.jqx-menu-popup').each(function() {
  $(this).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); // optional
    $(this).siblings('.jqx-menu-popup').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup" style="visibility: hidden;">One</div>
<div class="jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup" style="visibility: visible;">Two</div>
```

Note that if the element is dynamically generated, you'll have to hoist the scope and make use of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), which can be done by attaching the `mouseout` to an element that exists on DOM load instead of `.jqx-menu-popup`, with something like:

```
$('document').on('mouseout', '.jqx-menu-popup', function() { ...
```

If you need to find out which elements are currently visible, you can use:

```
if ($(this).css('visibility', 'visible')) { }
```

Comment: my issue is that i am trying to check if one of those 2 ".jqx-menu-popup" is visible and if i am hoverovering that visible ".jqx-menu-popup" but from the mouseout event of another html element  For instance $("#anotherelement").on({
        mouseleave: function () {       
    //check here if there is one of those guys visible and being hoverover  
           var a = $('.jqx-menu-popup:visible')
            if (!a.is(':hover')) {             
                    
                $('#' + 'jqxmenu' + elementHover).jqxMenu('close');
            }       
        }
    });