# Very Fast jQuery hover iteractions Reset

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm using the following code to swap `<div>` contents. It functions properly with the exception of the mousein and mouseout behavior of the boxes, which shows the wrong one. The class name "flipped" has display set equal to none. Should I check state, use setTimeout() or another method to prevent this behavior?

**The html**

```
<div class="videobox">
        <div class="unflipped">
            <img src="videoprop.jpg">
            <div class="desc_over">This is a description! Video Contains This!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flipped">This what displays when flipped 1!</div>
    </div>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(".videobox").hover(function(){
            $(this).children(".unflipped:first").fadeOut("fast",function(){
                $(this).next(".flipped:first").fadeIn("fast");
            });         
        },function(){           
            $(this).children(".flipped:first").fadeOut("fast",function(){
                $(this).prev(".unflipped").fadeIn("fast");
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separating them:

```
$('.videobox').find('.unflipped').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).next(".flipped").fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
$('.videobox').find('.flipped').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).prev(".unflipped").fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It displayed similar problem where the second div state is stuck on display if moved fast across.

Comment: check out this question for similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery

Comment: That question solution worked perfectly, thanks so much Mark.