# How do i check after .hover has started in jQuery that the mouse is still hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have li boxes that make this jQuery call when an end user hovers on them with his cursor:

```
$('.boxgrid.slidedown').hover(function(){
         $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'-150px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
        }, function() {
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'4px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
        });
```

Now i want to wait half a second after the user points his cursor so i could stall
the slidedown effect. if the mouse is still hovering then the slidedown will continue, if not then nothing should happen.

i tried using settimeout() without any luck. thank you.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: There's another post that is asking something similar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin for that, I think...

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html