# Unable to get mouseout to work properly on jquery Selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm trying to get the `Jquery Selectmenu plugin` to expand when I mouse over but close again when I leave it.

I decided to use the `MouseOver` and `MouseOut` events along with the `open` and `close` commands.

Problem is with how it works. It seems to create a some sort of fake menu outside of the div so as soon as I move over the options the menu closes again.

I reproduced this in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jc2bs/

I would love to be able to get this to work.

Also I would love if I was able to get it to close on `mouseout` if it was activated by a `mouseover` but not if it was activated by a click ( so if user clicked the menu it would stay open until he picked a option or clicked outside). But I guess that's a much more difficult scenario to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first (sub)question you can use the solution below. That work fine for me:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "#sel-button", function() {
    $('#sel').selectmenu('open');
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", "#sel-button, #sel-menu", function() {
    if (!$('#sel-menu').is(':hover')) {
        $('#sel').selectmenu('close');
    }
});
```

So, ​what I did. First, I changed deprecated `delegate` methods with new `on` method. Then, I used `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` (you can check [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) why). Consider that submenu has ID (`#sel-menu`) which is created by concatenating your `select` element ID with `"-menu"`. The same works for select button.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jc2bs/6/

---

Regarding the second (sub)question, we can use couple of tricks. One is using `data` to store a flag if the menu was clicked, and based on this decide whether to hide submenu on mouse leave or not.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jc2bs/7/

Comment: Thank you. I had to update my Jquery script from 1.5 to 1.7 to get it to work. I also looked closer into the classes and ids the selectmenu comes up with and that will help me with modeling the look a little bit. (beyond what themeroller does).

Comment: @IngóVals Good if my answer was helpful for you.

Comment: Could you think of a reason why the mouseleave wouldn't work properly on IE 9 (apart from IE being junk). He always seems to get true from the hover boolean and closes the menu.

Comment: @IngóVals I think because IE is junk mostly :) In the solution I used fast trick of checking whether cursor is over the element -- `:hover` selector which is not documented in JQuery docs (most probably because it is not supported by IE). If you really need IE support, you can replace `is(':hover')` with [more comprehensive method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery).

Comment: Well it didn't even work in Firefox either. I'll check out that other solution later.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the `mouseleave` event on the selectmenu itself to close the menu.

```
$('.ui-selectmenu-menu').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#sel').selectmenu('close');
});
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/5wExe/1

While your second requirement is theoretically possible I personally don't think that it's a good idea.  Users wouldn't think to click the menu if it shows up `onmouseover`.

Comment: Yes you are right about the second one, why would you click. But your fiddle doesn't close the menu if you leave via the #sel-button, it could be used as a similar feature :)