# A Function to Check if the Mouse is Still Hovering an Element Every 10 Milliseconds (and run a function if it is)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there is a function to be run after an element (e.g. div class="myiv") is hovered and check every X milliseconds if it's still hovered, and if it is, run another function.

EDIT: This did the trick for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/z8yaB/

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing.  There are good responses here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most purposes in simple interfaces, you may use jquery's hover function and simply store in a boolean somewhere if the mouse is hover. And then you may use a simple `setInterval` loop to check every ms this state. You yet could see in the first comment this answer in the linked duplicate (edit : and now in the other answers here).

But there are cases, especially when you have objects moving "between" the mouse and your object when hover generate false alarms.

For those cases, I made this function that checks if an event is really hover an element when jquery calls my handler :

```
var bubbling = {};
bubbling.eventIsOver = function(event, o) {
if ((!o) || o==null) return false;
var pos = o.offset();
var ex = event.pageX;
var ey = event.pageY;
if (
    ex>=pos.left
    && ex<=pos.left+o.width()
    && ey>=pos.top
    && ey<=pos.top+o.height()
) {
    return true;
}
return false;
};
```

I use this function to check that the mouse really leaved when I received the mouseout event :

```
 $('body').delegate(' myselector ', 'mouseenter', function(event) {
    bubbling.bubbleTarget = $(this);

    // store somewhere that the mouse is in the object

}).live('mouseout', function(event) {
    if (bubbling.eventIsOver(event, bubbling.bubbleTarget)) return;

    // store somewhere that the mouse leaved the object

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more what this function does exactly and how is it used?

Comment: I edited to precise it. Note that this is only useful when you have moving or appearing objects (I use this for a bubble library for very dynamic interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the hover() method which gives you this functionality out of the box:

```
$('.myiv').hover(
    function () {
        // the element is hovered over... do stuff

    }, 
    function () {
        // the element is no longer hovered... do stuff
    }
);
```

To check every x milliseconds if the element is still hovered and respond adjust to the following:

```
var x = 10; // number of milliseconds
var intervalId;
$('.myiv').hover(
    function () {
        // the element is hovered over... do stuff
        intervalId = window.setInterval(someFunction, x);
    }, 
    function () {
        // the element is no longer hovered... do stuff
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
);
```

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/z8yaB/

Comment: Yes, but the functions are separated. I am having issues with setInterval and clearInterval being in separate functions, so I will need to run a single function that will contain both the setInterval and clearInterval based on the condition if the mouse is hovering or not.

Comment: I am using the second code you provided and the setInterval runs (a function to scroll an element to the left with 10px).
However, when I mouseover the function keeps running. I am guessing the clearInterval is not set properly?

Comment: Having two different functions that use setInterval and clearInterval with a particular intervalId should have no negative effect as long as the intervalId is scoped correctly (i.e. available to both functions).

Comment: See this fiddle, it demonstrates what I think you are trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/z8yaB/

Comment: The JSfiddle you provided did the trick. I think I was referring to the function directly instead of assigning it to a var and referring to the var name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `variablename = setInterval(...)` to initiate a function repeatedly on mouseover, and `clearInterval(variablename)` to stop it on mouseout.

http://jsfiddle.net/XE8sK/

```
var marker;
$('#test').on('mouseover', function() {
    marker = setInterval(function() {
        $('#siren').show().fadeOut('slow');
    }, 500);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    clearInterval(marker);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval = 0;
$('.myiv').hover(
    function () {
        interval = setInterval(function(){
           console.log('still hovering');
        },1000);
    }, 
    function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
);
```