# Hover object comes up twice on background/foreground element when layers are overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please view this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AAd9b/1/

Every time I hover over this object, the overlapping object opens twice, how do I make it so it only fades in one time and stays there until i mouseout everything? So it doesn't matter if you're over the background or foreground object.

Comment: yeah I reread what you wrote and realized thats not what you were asking for.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.hover()` takes two arguments: `handlerIn` and `handlerOut`. If you supply only one callback, it's called on both events so you need to look at the event type to determine whether you `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

You're probably looking for this:

```
$('.someclass').hover(
    function() {
        //-- mouseenter
    },
    function() {
        //-- mouseleave
    }
);
```

The reason your element flashes under the mouse is because it triggers the `mouseleave` event on the `$('.someclass')` (because, technically, the mouse did leave that object). This is a tricky scenario. Would probably involve unbinding and rebinding the events while the mouse is over your `<p>`... or some fancy CSS trickery.

Or try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UBdgz/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="someclass">
        <a href="#">Hover Me</a>

    </div>
    <p>Only Once!</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var handleHover = function(evt) {
    switch (evt.type) {
        case 'mouseenter':
            $("p").fadeIn();
            break;
        case 'mouseleave':
            $("p").fadeOut();
            break;
    }
}
$(".wrapper").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', handleHover);
```

Comment: interesting.. let me give it a try.

Comment: well, its the same idea, same results.. Unless you know how to read if the object is currently hovered or not.?

Comment: Updated... had to modify the HTML a little.

Comment: This seemed to work fine in the example, so I'll give you the best answer.  Unfortunately wasn't for my code, due to the html structure constraints, so I used this post to help me with implementing the method i'm using now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery