# Disable mouseover event then re-enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How do I unbind or disable the mouse over after it's being hovered out then re-enable if the other box is faded out.

I tried the unbind, but seems that its not working, it just disables the whole thing.

I even tried a timeout but that is not working into my advantage.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#shopping_basket").mouseover(function() { 
            // set a timeout so that this event will not trigger twice when mouseover from the bottom
            setTimeout(function() {
                /*$("#shopping_basket").unbind(mouseover);*/
                $("#miniBasketDetails").fadeIn(500);
            },500);
            });     
        $("#miniBasketDetails").mouseleave(function() { $("#miniBasketDetails").fadeOut(500); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess try something like this:

```
$("#shopping_basket").bind('mouseover', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#shopping_basket").unbind('mouseover');
    $("#miniBasketDetails").fadeIn(500);
  }, 500);

 //Re-enable as needed: $("#shopping_basket").bind('mouseover', function(){});
});
```

This code is not tested, but should work.

I think your problem was that you passed `mouseover` into `.unbind()` as a variable, not a string. This is why the "whole thing" was disabled, because JavaScript was looking for a variable named `mouseover`, which was not defined, and caused your code to break. Try it like this: `.unbind('mouseover')`.

Comment: Excellent thank you very much for the explanation and help! This is what i was trying to do.

Comment: @EmmanuelCorwinFlossie Could you please click the green check mark next to my answer to accept it, if you found it helpful.

Comment: I would love to but my rep is to low :(

Comment: @EmmanuelCorwinFlossie Your rep is too low to upvote, but you should be able to accept answers right off the bat: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: aha didnt know that, thanks spryno724 just done that, and learned something new again :)

Comment: @EmmanuelCorwinFlossie Sorry to be so persistent, but you selected another person's answer. ;)

Comment: Damn, i stackoverflow is pretty new to me, didnt, know you could like one answer per question, sorry for the hassle :) And thanks for your patience

Comment: @EmmanuelCorwinFlossie No problem. Now you know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the algorythm you're looking for, it is [based on answers shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery).
Here is [the fiddle and the code](http://jsfiddle.net/rVEbp/):

```js
$("#shopping_basket").hover(function() {
    $("#miniBasketDetails").fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
    $("#miniBasketDetails").data('is_over', false);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$('#miniBasketDetails').data('is_over')) {
            //if not hovered over the #miniBasketDetails in 650 miliseconds after mouseleave
            $("#miniBasketDetails").fadeOut(500);
        }
    }, 650);
});

$("#miniBasketDetails").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).data('is_over', true);
});

$('#miniBasketClose').click(function() {
    $("#miniBasketDetails").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).data('is_over', false);
    });
});
```

The `span#miniBasketClose` is just one optional "Close button", not necessary for functionality of the code. Its functionality can be substituted (if needed) for example also with hovering over some other elements.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the reply, with the previous answer i have actually established a close button, but thanks for the answer this is a great sollution.