# How do I check if focus has switched to a new element after another has blurred using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, browser, focus, coffeescript

I have a text input on my page. When it receives focus, a select box appears underneath it. When it loses focus, I want the select box to disappear *unless* the focus has shifted to the select box. Sounds simple enough but I struck a problem.

I set up the event handlers like so (using coffeescript)

```
jQuery ->
  $('td.description input').focus -> showItemSelector()
  $('td.description input').blur -> hideItemSelector()
```

`showItemSelector()` and `hideItemSelector()` are defined like so

```
showItemSelector () ->
  $('#item-selector').show()

hideItemSelector () ->
  unless $('#item-selector select').is(':focus')
    $('#item-selector').hide()
```

But it doesn't work. The item selector is always hidden after the input loses focus. I did some experimenting and my suspicion was confirmed. The `hideItemSelector` function is being executed before focus is shifted to the new element (which makes some sense - the browser presumably takes focus from the first element, triggering my function, before it assigns focus to the next element). The following bit of code demonstrates this;

```
hideItemSelector = () ->
    focus = -> console.log $('select#category').is(':focus')
    focus()
    setTimeout focus, 1000
```

This returns false and then true in the console. The delay gives the browser time to shift the focus.

So my question is, how can I do what I want to do without using a setTimeout? If nothing else works then this will have to do, but it seems like a flawed approach.

Comment: I wouldn't really call `setTimeout` to be a flawed approach. Sometimes it's inevitable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with assigning global var and changing its value from `true` to `false` as a user moves on and off the object, for example:

```
$('#yourElement').mouseenter(function() {
  isHovered = true;
}).mouseleave(function() {
   isHovered = false;
 });
```

There is also a way that works in all browsers except Internet Explorer but I wouldn't recommend using it as it's using invalid pseudo-selector:

```
if ($('#hello').is(':hover')) {
      alert('hello');
 }
```

Other than that you will have to find plugins for that. Here is the self made plugin by [SpYk3HH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900807/spyk3hh) which can be found here: [jsFiddle isHover Plugin Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/2FZVW/). I would also recommend reading: [How do I check if the mouse is over an element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery). I think it will be useful to you.