# jQuery plugin: ":hover" doesnt work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a jQuery plugin which makes an element pulse. It's working great in Chrome and Internet Explorer 9. In Internet Explorer 8, it's not working after the setTimeout call.

I've created a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Guykp/
Here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.pulseEffect = function(delay, duration) {
    var $element, animateOptions;
    $element = $(this);
    if (!$element.is(":hover")) {
      animateOptions = {
        opacity: $element.css("opacity") === "1" ? .6 : 1
      };
      $element.animate(animateOptions, duration);
    }
    return setTimeout((function() {
      return $element.pulseEffect(delay, duration);
    }), delay + duration);
  };

  $("#pulse-element").pulseEffect(0, 1000);
});
```

How can I make it working in Internet Explorer 8?

This is the error message from Internet Explorer 8: **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover**

**This is the solution:**
[How do I check if the mouse is over an element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery/2846405#2846405)

Comment: You can't return a value from a function inside `setTimeout`.

Comment: I know, but the code is written using CoffeeScript. CoffeeScript returns the last statement inside each function. But thanks! :-)

Comment: There are numerous issues with your code. First of all, `setTimeout` only returns the TimeoutHandle. Secondly, everyone knows `:hover` doesn't play well with web browsers. Instead of `return setTimeout(...);` write it as `setTimeout(...); return $this;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery/2846405#2846405

Comment: @Martin, if the code is written in CoffeeScript, please tag with the coffeescript tag so that we know what language you are speaking.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: The question has nothing to do with CoffeeScript.  CoffeeScript is a language that compiles *into* JavaScript.  This is the output, it's JavaScript.

Comment: I've fixed the tag. Anyway, CoffeeScript or not, it does not make sense. setTimeout() is asynchronous: it can't returning something if it didn't happen there and then.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, The code you're looking at is JavaScript (compiled from CoffeeScript). So it's not CoffeeScript anymore :-)

Comment: @Martin / Rocket - I disagree. Just because I write a program in C or PHP, I don't throw in dumps of assembly/opcodes on SO. Also, if that is really javascript, then my and Mike's argument about setTimeout holds (not that I doubted it).

Comment: @RocketHazmat, @Martin, if the code I'm looking at is CoffeeScript, then returning from `setTimeout` is okay. If the code I'm looking at is JavaScript, the returning from `setTimeout` is not okay. @Martin, in his creplay to @RockHazmat's comment to that effect, said it's CoffeeScript, so it's okay. How can I tell what's right?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Returning from `setTimeout` is fine, it just doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @RocketHazmat IE8 also doesn't support malformed code.

Comment: @Christian: Nor do most other browsers.

Comment: Really? Ever heard about jQuery chaining? You think it would chain if it kept returning nulls or just numbers?

Comment: @Christian: Chaining?  Who are you talking to?

Comment: @RocketHazmat `$('a').pulseEffect().click(); // error, null not an object`

Comment: @Christian: Oh!  I'm very sorry.  I was ignoring the title.

Comment: Good. Slightly offending text removed :)

Comment: Thank you for spotting the wrong assumption in the title of the question. I've updated the title and added the solution for future readers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not have a `:hover` selector anymore.  Some browsers support `:hover` natively, but others don't.  jQuery used to use its CSS engine, Sizzle, to to this, but it no longer does.

Try using the `hover` (or `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`) event(s).

Answer (score 0):

its like

`$('li:hover).css('display', 'block');` is equivalent to `$().css('display', 'block');`

like Rocket Hazmat said use the jquery `hover`