# jQuery display box on hover and hide on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, i am trying to create a box should pop out when a link is hovered,

well i got the basic covered, but for some reason i couldn't fully accomplish what i am trying to do.

as you can see on here, http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/1/ (sorry its a poor recreation of the problem i am having)

What i am trying to do is to make the box (`TEST`) visible if `HOVER HERE` is hovered and box should visible if mouse is hovered inside.

when the mouse entered `TEST`, it works correctly, however, when it is hovered to other `OTHER` and a empty space, it doesn't work correctly as the `TEST` box is still visible.

How do i make the `TEST` box hide if mouse hovered on OTHER & empty space
Thanks and i am newbie to jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery#answer-1670561):

```js
var $link = $(".link");
var $box = $("#box");

$link.mouseenter(function() {
  clearTimeout($box.data('timeoutId'));
  $box.show(200);
}).mouseleave(function() {
  var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    $box.hide(200);
  }, 650);
  $box.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
});

$box.mouseenter(function() {
  clearTimeout($box.data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function() {
  var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    $box.hide(200);
  }, 650);
  $box.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
});
```

```css
.link {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#box {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link">Hover me</a>
<div id="box">Surprise!</div>
```

Comment: erm, its not a typo, i need the box to visible if hovered inside.

Comment: This works unless you also want the TEST to be visible if the mouse is also over the TEST text...

Comment: @joh i updated my solution http://jsfiddle.net/brunoscopelliti/EpV87/8/
now the box is visible if hovered inside

Answer (score 0):

You were handling an mouseleave inside another mouseleave handler in the [version I checked](http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/1/) and had a typo in your selector 
`$('#abc').mouseleave(function(){...` 
should be 
`$('.abc').mouseleave(function(){...`

## Version you posted originally

http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/1/

### HTML

```
<a class="abc">ABC</a>
<div id="def">TEST</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$('.abc').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $('#def').show(200);
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('#abc').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#def').hide(200);
    });
});
```

## Solution

http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/6/

### HTML

```
<a class="abc">ABC</a>
<div id="def" style="display: none;">TEST</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$('.abc')
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
        $("#def").show();            
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function () {
        $("#def").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another div to contain the two elements:

```
<div id="container">
    <a class="abc">ABC</a>
    <div id="def">TEST</div>
</div>
```

This way you can make the TEST div disappear when the mouse leaves the container div.​

```
$('.abc').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $('#def').show(200);
});
$('#container').mouseleave(function(e){
    $('#def').hide(200);
});
```

You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/7/).