# jQuery display box on element hover and stays on while hovering box

Tags: jquery, hover

What I'm trying to achieve is using jQuery to display a box when hovering a different element above it.

I've found what I need in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975921/jquery-display-box-on-hover-and-hide-on-mouseleave). You can also check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoscopelliti/EpV87/8/). The problem is that this solution doesn't fully meet my needs, because I need the `<a>` element to be shown on hover state while hovering the box below. When you hover the box, the `<a>` element loses the hover state, which is pretty standard, but I need it to be shown in hover state.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to literally put the `div` inside of the `a`. Since the `a` is the parent no matter where you hover in the `div` `a:hover` will be triggered. Otherwise you just need a simple timeout and check `.on('mouseenter'` & `.on('mouseleave'` for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check updated source code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpV87/258/).

First, I included the div to your html link.

```
<a class="abc">
    <div class="test">ABC</div>
    <div id="def">TEST</div>
</a>
```

Second, I added a hover design. You can notice that the link hover isn't gone when you move your mouse to the div.

```
a.abc:hover {color:red;}
```

Please note that I didn't add anything to your javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: Just like Adam mentioned it, I guess this is the best solution. I was trying to avoid adding another element, but I guess this is the best and simplest way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you so much for your help, guys! :)