# background blackout on Nav mouseover not to strobe

Tags: jquery, navigation

i have a navigation that i want to have a background blackout similar to that of [selfridges](https://www.selfridges.com/).

I have the basic functionality setup [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Flakx/vbc3U/)

jQuery:

```
jQuery('<div class="backmask"></div>').insertAfter('.wrapper');


function removeBlack() {

jQuery('.nav-container').removeClass('navmask');
jQuery('.backmask').fadeOut(300);

}

function addBlack() {

jQuery('.nav-container').addClass('navmask');
jQuery('.backmask').fadeIn(100);

}

jQuery('.nav li').hover(addBlack, removeBlack);
```

however, when you mouse from one element to another it strobes rather than just keeps the black background in tact.

I've tried various 'if' statements within the 2 functions and i keep getting to a stage where i think yes it's nearly done, but then it fails again.

ps i do not want to change #nav li to just #nav because then if my navigation doesn't stretch the whole width of the navigation i don't want poeple mousing into empty space for it to black the background out.

any ideas? am i just missing one critical jquery selector? e.g. treat all those #nav li as one element?

thanks.

###EDIT

since the helpful answer from mornaner this is my code now:

```
jQuery('<div class="backmask"></div>').insertAfter('.wrapper');


function removeBlack() {

jQuery('.nav-container').removeClass('navmask');
jQuery('.backmask').fadeOut(200);

}

function addBlack() {

    jQuery('.nav-container').addClass('navmask');
    jQuery('.backmask').fadeIn(100);

}

jQuery('#pronav li').hover(function(){
 clearTimeout(jQuery(this).data('timeoutId'));
addBlack();
}, function(){
var nav = jQuery('#pronav li');
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
    removeBlack();
}, 80);
//set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
nav.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1670561/966865) I did it:

```
jQuery('.nav li').hover(function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
        addBlack();
    }, function(){
        var someElement = $('.nav li');
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        removeBlack();
    }, 150);
    //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
    someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fap5n/)

You can adjust the timeout time, with 150ms it looks smooth to me, but you can lower it if you feel it's too long.

Comment: Yep thats done the trick :) thanks - i knew it was one seemingly simple thing i was missing. I kept stumbling accross Timeout but couldn't quite figure out how to uterlise it. So learn't something today (havn't quite reached that chapter yet :) )