# jQuery hover error in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

In Google Chrome and IE, this jQuery code is throwing an error

> "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover".

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('body').mouseup(function(){
        var isHovered = $('#QRcodeScanner').is(':hover'); 
        if(!isHovered) {
          closeScannerService.prepForClosing();
        }
      });
    });
```

Is there something I can do about this error? Because I think, this error prevents IE for opening the webcam...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497457/ishover-is-broken-as-of-jquery-1-9-how-to-fix

Comment: While there's no accepted answer, I feel like there are good enough answers in the linked QA, that's why I closed.

Comment: @JohnDevelops That dupe seems to provide a more comprehensive answer to the `:hover` issue

Comment: Lots about it on SO it seems :)