# fixing deprecated js code

Tags: javascript, hover, deprecated

i'm currently working on a chat extension for phpBB 3.1.x-3.2.x and need to replace a deprecated function in my js. i can't seems to get anything to work.

here's what i have

```
        setInterval(function(){
        var $chatscroll = $('div.shouts');
        if($chatscroll.is(':hover')) {
            $chatscroll.stop();
        }
        else {
           $chatscroll.scrollTop($('#chat').height());
        }
    }, 200);
```

i just can't seem to get the :hover replaced with something that works.

Comment: What is deprecated? Are you refering to this e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497457/ishover-is-broken-as-of-jquery-1-9-how-to-fix  ???  If ya, to handle multiple elements in set, you could use: `if($chatscroll.filter(function(){
          return $(this).is(':hover');
        }).length){...}else {...}`

Comment: and that worked perfectly. thank you