# if class is not hover - doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Click anywhere except `#menut` closes `.m2wrap`. It works.

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  if (!$('#menut').is(':hover')) {
    $('.m2wrap').slideUp();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menut'>
  <div class='m1wrap'>
    <div class='m1'>SKY</div>
    <div class='m2wrap'>
      <div class='m2'>SEA</div>
      <div class='m2'>EARTH</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I replace `#menut` with `.m1wrap` - it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  if (!$('.m1wrap').is(':hover')) {
    $('.m2wrap').slideUp();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menut'>
  <div class='m1wrap'>
    <div class='m1'>SKY</div>
    <div class='m2wrap'>
      <div class='m2'>SEA</div>
      <div class='m2'>EARTH</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case console shows the error - `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover...`

Actually, what I need is - `if multiple class is not hover...`

Any help?

Comment: Post some HTML. If you right click on your area and do *Inspect Element* and hover over your `m1wrap` div, does it have a height? Or is it `0`?

Comment: I just edited your question and made each of your examples its own code snippet. It looks like they're both working...

Comment: I have the same as J. Titus -- I checked in case it was a browser issue, but both worked for me in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Edge.

Comment: try thin https://jsfiddle.net/Devasnsh_Kumar/7gfmnmtz/

Comment: both are working fine for me .

Comment: @J.Titus, I checked console and saw an error. Please check my update

Comment: @RobWilkins, please check my post update - console error

Comment: @Santi, yes, height of `.m1wrap` is 30 px

Comment: Check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497457/ishover-is-broken-as-of-jquery-1-9-how-to-fix and see if you could check the length of the returned Jquery object. If it's more than 0 then the element is being hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).click(function() {
  if($('#menut:hover').length == 0) {
    $('.m2wrap').slideUp();
  }
});
```

This is following the answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497457/ishover-is-broken-as-of-jquery-1-9-how-to-fix).

Comment: @bonaca I updated the condition for the `if` statement. Could you try again?

Comment: Solved, finally. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue I fixed mine by just removing the semicolon before the hover as below

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl2-controls").mouseleave(function() {
    if(!$('.owl2-controls').is(':hover')){
      $('.owl2-controls').hide();
    };
  });
 });`
```

To

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl2-controls").mouseleave(function() {
    if(!$('.owl2-controls').is('hover')){
      $('.owl2-controls').hide();
    };
  });
 });`
```

No error thrown now.