# Detect Hover for two intersecting Circular elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i did  an example on jsFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/aRWhm/ ) , the idea is to know when i'm over lets say the intersection between the red and the blue circle.
but the problem is that every time i reach the intersection, the class "is-over" of the red circle is removed.
Html:

```
<div>
    <span id="Div1"></span>
    <span id="Div2"></span>
    <span id="Div3"></span>
    <span id="Div4"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 div {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 950px;
    }
    span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.5;
        border-radius: 999px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #Div1 {
        background-color: #FF0000;
        height: 200px;
        left: 50px;
        top: 80px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    #Div2 {
        background-color: #0000FF;
        height: 150px;
        left: 40px;
        top: 230px;
        width: 150px;
    }
    #Div3 {
        background-color: #008000;
        height: 250px;
        left: 100px;
        top: 190px;
        width: 250px;
    }
    #Div4 {
        background-color: #FFFF00;
        height: 100px;
        left: 200px;
        top: 130px;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Div1").hover(
    function () {  
        $(this).addClass("is-over");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("is-over");
    }
);
$("#Div2").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("is-over");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("is-over");
    }
);
$("#Div3").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("is-over");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("is-over");
    }
);
$("#Div4").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("is-over");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("is-over");
    }
);
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you should be using proper graphics - ie SVG - for this rather than html+css.

Comment: Any suggestion on where to start?

Comment: Try [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/); it's a nice JS library for drawing SVG graphics on your page and interracting with them.

Comment: d3 is good for SVG manipulation as well, although I don't really like it for its stated data purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

First, the Code:

```
(function($){ 
    $.mlp = {x:0,y:0}; // Mouse Last Position
    function documentHandler(){
        var $current = this === document ? $(this) : $(this).contents();
        $current.mousemove(function(e){jQuery.mlp = {x:e.pageX,y:e.pageY}});
        $current.find("iframe").load(documentHandler);
    }
    $(documentHandler);
    $.fn.ismouseover = function(overThis) {  
        var result = false;
        this.eq(0).each(function() {  
                var $current = $(this).is("iframe") ? $(this).contents().find("body") : $(this);
                var offset = $current.offset();             
                result =    offset.left<=$.mlp.x && offset.left + $current.outerWidth() > $.mlp.x &&
                            offset.top<=$.mlp.y && offset.top + $current.outerHeight() > $.mlp.y;
        });  
        return result;
    };  
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myDiv").mousemove(
        function() {
            $("#myDiv").children("span").each(function(){
                if($(this).ismouseover())
                    $(this).addClass("is-over");
                else
                    $(this).removeClass("is-over");
            });
        });
});
```

Now an explanation:

I stole the `.ismouseover()` code shamelessly from [this answer by Ivan Castellanos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622583/1168038) and repurposed it to your needs. Form there I used a `.mousemove()` event to fire every time you're in the parent container, which you can see in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJpcF/1/)** needed to be given height and width parameters to ensure that it had a bounding box.

Lastly I simply check to see which circles you're over, and add the `is-over` class to them. The Fiddle is based off Anton's work, although it provides intersection support instead of moving one to the top.

Hope this helps.