# Jquery Mouseover mouseleave using .on function

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm trying to implement a tagging system using jquery.

I have two div, .tagged and .taggeditem

When a user hovers on .tagged I would want taggeditem to fadeIn. However, taggeditem is about 50 pixels away from .tagged so when the user mouse leaves .tagged .taggeditem fades away. I decided to set a delay of 6 seconds after which taggeditem would fadeOut. Is there a way I can prevent taggeditem from fading out if the users mouse is over tagged item.

```
Here is the script I am using 

       $('.tagged').on({
mouseenter: function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
    var id_= $(this).attr('post-value');
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#taggeditem'+id).fadeIn(200);
    $('#taggeditemmask'+id_).fadeIn(200);
},
mouseleave: function () {
   var id_ = $(this).attr('post-value');
   var id = $(this).attr('value');
  if ($('#taggeditem'+id).is(':hover')) {

       }else{
       $('#taggeditem'+id).delay(600).fadeOut(200);
       $('#taggeditemmask'+id_).delay(600).fadeOut(200);
}
}
    });
```

Comment: Can you setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this post [How do I check if the mouse is over an element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery/1670561#1670561) that uses  a settimout on mouseenter and mouseleave of the element you want to fadeout.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/RJCAJ/) example based on your code.

Code below

```
$(function()
{
    var timeout;

    $('.tagged').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('#taggeditem').fadeIn(200);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){
              $('#taggeditem').fadeOut(200);
            }, 600);

        }
    });

      $('#taggeditem').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
               timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                  $(this).fadeOut(200);
               }, 600);
            }
       });      
  });
```