# Hover state is maintained during a transition even if the element has gone

Tags: javascript, css, hover, css-transitions, css-transforms

Consider a simple element, and its associated CSS:

```html
<div id="content">Hover me !</div>
```

```css
#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#content:hover {
    transform: translateY(500px);
    transition: transform 1s 500ms;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/U44Zf/)</kbd>

The principle is straightforward: while the element is hovered, it must go down. The problem is, when **the mouse doesn't move**, that the `:hover` state is maintained even if the element is not physically below the mouse anymore (due to the translation). The state seems to be updated only after an mouse move.

[image: Illustration of the problem]
*Notice the cursor (a pointer) and its relative position with the element!*

That's a real problem when a JavaScript function must be executed only if the mouse is on an element, after a `timeout`:

```js
// The mouseleave event will not be called during the transition,
// unless the mouse move !

element.on('mouseenter', executeAfterTimeout);
element.on('mouseleave', cancelTimeout);
```

So here are my questions:

1. Is this behaviour *normal* (compliant with the norms)?
2. What are the solutions to avoid this problem?

***Edit :*** To give you a context, here is what I want to do concretely: with JavaScript, I display a tooltip when the mouse is on an element (and hide it when the mouse leaves it). But the same element can be `transform`-ed when the user click on it. If the user simply clicks without moving the mouse, the tooltip will remain displayed, which is a real problem. How can I detect that the element is gone?

Comment: this behavior is somehow kind of normal, element is still using the room your pointed at , but drawn lower via translate. You might experiment same funny behavior with relative nd coordonates instead translate.

Comment: @GCyrillus Do you have any link to a normative document?

Comment: From an online editor like this : http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/pen

Comment: Well the only normative document I have found is: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes . It says only something about the activation of hover: "The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element (with some pointing device)", so it is clear that hover can only be activated by a mouse movement and not by a translation. Probably the deactivation is implemented like this aswell

Comment: The behaviour seems normal according to the standards. What is exactly what you need to accomplish?

Comment: @Blackhole I've added a possible answer

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable and normal behaviour, across browsers and devices. The state of an element (`hover` etc) is not updated unless the mouse moves. If it was, think of the memory it would use it a browser. It would make it unusable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Part 1 of your question:

> The principle is straightforward: while the element is hovered, it
>   must go down. The problem is, when the mouse doesn't move, that the
>   :hover state is maintained even if the element is not physically below
>   the mouse anymore (due to the translation). The state seems to be
>   updated only after an mouse move.
>
> So here are my questions:
>
> 1. Is this behaviour normal (compliant with the norms)?

Yes. This behaviour is normal. Although not specified verbatim in the standards, it is mentioned in detail here: **http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105**

**Take this fiddle as reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/h7tb9/3/**

The upper `div` has mouse-events bound to it directly. The lower `div` has mouse-event bound to its parent. Pick up the lower one. Move the mouse slowly at one edge and watch the console to see what happens.

1. You touch the edge and `mouseover` and `mouseenter` are fired in quick succession (hover).
2. As a result the inner `div` translates.
3. Do nothing. No event is fired and so nothing happens.
4. Move the mouse inside the outer `div`. `mousemove` fires and the inner `div` is still translated.
5. Slowly move the mouse out. `mouseout` and `mouseleave` are fired in quick succession and the inner `div` translates back to its original position.

This is described here: **http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#events-mouseevents** under the section *Mouse Event Order*.

Step 3 above is important. Because you are doing nothing, no event is fired and hence nothing happens. If the inner `div` were to bounce back to its original position in this step, then it would mean that an activation happened without any event!

This is in line with the definition of *event* as the document in this section: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#glossary-event says:

> An event is the representation of some occurrence (such as a mouse
>   click on the presentation of an element, the removal of child node
>   from an element, or any number of other possibilities) which is
>   associated with its event target. Each event is an instantiation of
>   one specific event type.

Now have a look at the document here: **http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#event-flow**, just before the *section 3.2* starts, it says:

> After an event completes all the phases of its propagation path, its
>   Event.currentTarget must be set to null and the Event.eventPhase must
>   be set to 0 (NONE). All other attributes of the Event (or interface
>   derived from Event) are unchanged (including the Event.target
>   attribute, which must continue to reference the event target).

***The last line (in parentheses) is important. The event.target continues to reference the event target even after the event completes.***

Now pick the upper `div` in the fiddle for reference. On `mouseenter` the `div` itself is translated. ***It does not matter if it moves away from below the mouse pointer. The event.target is still referencing to it*** and if no other mouse event occurs, nothing happens and it remains translated. The moment you move your mouse (anywhere in or out), the activation occurs on the event.target (which is still this `div`) and ***now the user-agent finds that the mouse pointer is no longer over the element*** and immediately `mouseout` and `mouseleave` events fire (after firing `mousemove` of course) causing the `div` to translate back.

### Part 2 of your question:

> 2.What are the solutions to avoid this problem?
>
> Edit : To give you a context, here is what I want to do concretely:
>   with JavaScript, I display a tooltip when the mouse is on an element
>   (and hide it when the mouse leaves it). But the same element can be
>   transform-ed when the user click on it. If the user simply clicks
>   without moving the mouse, the tooltip will remain displayed, which is
>   a real problem. How can I detect that the element is gone?

If you look at the implementation in the lower `div` in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/h7tb9/2/ ; as compared to the upper div, there is no flutter/jitter when mousing over. This is because rather than the `div` itself, the events are being handled on the parent.

So, that could be one solution for your use case.

**See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/nR8t9/9/**

This addresses your edit. Tooltip gets displayed on `mouseover`. Tooltip gets hidden on `mouseleave`. The same element can be transform-ed when you `click`. If you simply `click` without moving the mouse, the tooltip hides.

Here, if you `click`, the element is being translated and then no further `hover` action would happen. The tooltip itself is implemented using a `:before` pseudo-element. This separates out the tooltip and the element which you want to change after `click`. You still handle events on the element itself. No need for timeout as it is handled by the css itself. If you `mouseout`, the tooltip will hide after a delay.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's a solution to use JavaScript and a class to indicate the status. In your case, you could use `mouseover` event to toggle a class like this:

```
$('#content').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('down');
});
```

CSS

```
#content.down  {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    transform:translateY(300px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U44Zf/4/)

The other solution is to use a wrapper as hover block

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">Hover me !</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper:hover #content  {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    transform:translateY(300px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U44Zf/6/)

Notice, this two solutions have different behaviors for different requirements.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to look at this problem another way: if an element is going to be transitioned when you `click` on it. Why not just execute your callback on `click` instead of `mouseleave`?

I am assuming the tooltip has some connection to the element you `mouseenter`, in which case `mouseleave` and `click` are effectively the same - they both cause mouse pointer to not be over the element anymore (regardless of how browser behaves).

PS: note that in your example, how `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` fire also depends on whether you set the `transition` as default property or as a `:hover` state property, since this looks like an area where browser vendors are free to optimize as they please, you should probably avoid they in the first place.

- http://jsfiddle.net/U44Zf/13/ - `transition on #content:hover`
- http://jsfiddle.net/U44Zf/14/ - `transition on #content`

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is normal to prevent the element from bouncing under the cursor. Imagine the transition would revert as soon as the element is away from the cursor. As soon as the cursor has left the element, it would go back, so the cursor is again above the element and it moves down. This way it would bounce up and down at the edge of the cursor.

One solution would be to implement the transition with JavaScript instead of CSS, then the element will "bounce". But is this really the desired behavior? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is normal and can not be changed. It is correctly implemented according to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) @[Stasik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383834/stasik) linked to.

If you have to change this behavior, you could use javascript with jquery instead of css pseudo classes. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6fSJ/) to demonstrate a possible approach using the `.ismouseover()` jQuery extension by @[Ivan Castellanos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800817/ivan-castellanos) provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery/6622583#6622583).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is the behaviour you want to accomplish. Some are example styles, adjust as you please.

http://jsfiddle.net/U44Zf/9/

```
.tooltip {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s 500ms;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#content:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform:translateX(100px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
}
#content {
    transition: 1s 500ms;
    transition-property: background-color, color;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
#content.active {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
#content.active .tooltip {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
}
```

I've added this javascript snippet to control the click state

```
$('#content').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```