# DropDown on MouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

onmouseOver of eacuser i want to show the change password as a dropdown(as can seen in attached image) but with my code changes i am getting change password next to eacuser link.Can anyone please give me some hint how to achieve.I attached the two image file.please check for reference[image: below image is with my code change] [image: actually i want in this way]

```
    <div id="appLinks">
    <ul id="appLinks_list" class="nav">
        <span id="appLink_csrname" class="ui-state-default csrname"><a onmouseover="onMouseOver()">eacuser</span>

        <li id="appLink_chngpwd" class="ui-state-default chngpwd">Change Password</li>
            <li id="appLink_about" rtlOrder="3"><a href="javascript:openAboutDialog();"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.information")}" border="0px;" align="top">About</a></li>
            <li id="appLink_logout" rtlOrder="2"><a href="$link.getContextPath()/logout.do"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.logout")}" border="0px;" align="top">LogOut</a></li>
            <li id="appLink_help" rtlOrder="1"><a target="eachelp" href="$msg.get("eac.helpPath")"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.help")}"  border="0px;" align="top">Help</a></li>

    </span>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".csrname").mouseleave(function(){
         //$('#appLink_chngpwd').hide();
         $(".csrname li").css("display","none"); 
        });
        $(".csrname").mouseover(function(){
         //$('#appLink_chngpwd').show();
         $(".csrname li").css("display","block"); 
        });

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you *actually* tried?

Comment: just added the mouseover function but how to achieve display change password functionality not getting                                       <span id="appLink_csrname" class="ui-state-default csrname"><a onmouseover="onMouseOver()">eacuser</span>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if the mouse is over an element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273566/how-do-i-check-if-the-mouse-is-over-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: first of all close the firs <a> tag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r6u3n/

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this only by CSS, for that you need to edit you Markup.

[Check this demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbLms)

CSS

```
#appLinks_list ul {
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  top:30px;
  width: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}
#appLinks_list li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc
}
#appLinks_list li:hover {
  background: #ccc
}
```

I have just added the minimum code for showing dropdown on `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand, use code like this.replace the div id's with your div ids.

```
$( "#appLink_csrname" ).mouseover(function() {
  $('#changepasswordDivId').show();
});
$( "#changepasswordDivId" ).click(function() {
  $('#popup').show();// use facebox or fancy box code that you are using for popup here.
});
```

Comment: but i dont have #changepasswordDivId' in my code, thats why im trying to know how can i add this particular id so that i can able to see the change password link

Answer (score 0):

I think it's although fault in your html code, watch span and a tags

```
<ul id="appLinks_list" class="nav">
    <span id="appLink_csrname" class="ui-state-default csrname"><a href="#">eacuser</a>

    <li id="appLink_chngpwd" class="ui-state-default chngpwd">Change Password</li>
        <li id="appLink_about" rtlOrder="3"><a href="javascript:openAboutDialog();"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.information")}" border="0px;" align="top">About</a></li>
        <li id="appLink_logout" rtlOrder="2"><a href="$link.getContextPath()/logout.do"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.logout")}" border="0px;" align="top">LogOut</a></li>
        <li id="appLink_help" rtlOrder="1"><a target="eachelp" href="$msg.get("eac.helpPath")"><img src="${link.getContextPath()}${msg.get("icon.help")}"  border="0px;" align="top">Help</a></li>

</span>
</ul>
```

then

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.csrname').bind('mouseenter', function () {
        $('.csrname', '#appLink_csrname').show()
    }
    $('.csrname').bind('mouseleave', function () {
        $('.csrname', '#appLink_csrname').hide()
    }
})
</script>
```