# Prevent mouse out occurring when

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image of a face that when a user hovers over a menu drops out of the mouth. When the user hovers outside the face I want the menu to return to its original position again. The issue I am having is that the menu is also separate to the face, although it actually is positioned in the middle of the face, so when the user hovers on the menu the animation is reversed.

I have done things like `mouse-events: none;` but that doesn't solve my issue unfortunately.

My code looks like this

```js
 var tongueOut = false;
    
    $('.face-hover-zone').mouseover(function(){
  if(tongueOut == false) {
   animateTongueOut.play();
   tongueOut = true;
  }
 });

    $('.face-hover-zone').mouseleave(function(){
  if(tongueOut == true) {
   animateTongueOut.reverse();
   tongueOut = false;
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="face"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="face-hover-zone"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Away</li>
      <li>Results</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You don't want to prevent the mouseleave, you want to check in the mouseleave if the cursor is not over the menu.

Comment: how would you go about implementing that ? @AntoineB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13382705/3876196

Comment: Try `$(":hover")` selector, or `.hover()` method. Also, I don't know your code, but this should probably be done with JS, but CSS-only.

Comment: In my last comment I meant to say this should probably _not_ be done with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you put the menu in the "face-hover-zone" div... Seen as you are saying you have positioned it there already.

```html
<div class="face-hover-zone">

    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Away</li>
      <li>Results</li>
    </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post this as a comment?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Post the demo of working code and this becomes an answer :)